# How can I remove objects from the array

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, object

Initially i have this json, i need to leave in "names": [] only those objects where name is not repeated

```
{
        "type": "city",
        "names": [
            {
                "name": "Citi1",
                "index": 0,
                "names": [
                    0,
                    1,
                    4
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Citi1",
                "index": 1,
                "names": [
                    0,
                    1,
                    4
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Citi2",
                "index": 2,
                "names": [
                    2,
                    3
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Citi1",
                "index": 4,
                "names": [
                    0,
                    1,
                    4
                ]
            }
        ]
```

How can I remove objects from the ["names"] array with repeated "name"?

For example, I need to delete objects where citi1 is repeated and leave only 1 of them
Expected object

```
{
        "type": "city",
        "names": [
            {
                "name": "Citi1",
                "index": 0,
                "names": [
                    0,
                    1,
                    4
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Citi2",
                "index": 2,
                "names": [
                    2,
                    3
                ]
            },
           
        ]
```

code which i tried

```
 for(let i = 0; i < queueTypes.length; i++){
queueTypes[i]["names"].forEach(  function (item, index) {
                   
                    let tmpIndex = index;

                    for(let j = 0; j < queueTypes[i]["names"].length; j++){
                         if(queueTypes[i]["names"][j].name == item.name){
                             if( tmpIndex != j ){
                     
                                delete queueTypes[i]["names"][j]

                             }
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

trying to loop through this array and check if the names are the same, but the index does not match the element I am checking against

Comment: What have you tried so far? Pls show us your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter duplicate objects based on the `name` key in the `names` array, you can store a map of unique names and filter out any names that are already in the map.

```js
const myData = {
  "type": "city",
  "names": [
      {
          "name": "Citi1",
          "index": 0,
          "names": [
              0,
              1,
              4
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "Citi1",
          "index": 1,
          "names": [
              0,
              1,
              4
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "Citi2",
          "index": 2,
          "names": [
              2,
              3
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "Citi1",
          "index": 4,
          "names": [
              0,
              1,
              4
          ]
      }
  ]
};

const transform = data => {
  const unique = {};

  return {
    ...data,
    names: data.names.filter(({ name }) => {
      if (unique[name]) {
         return false;
       } else {
         unique[name] = true;
         return true;
       }
     })
  };
};

console.log(transform(myData));
```